# implementing HTML form for select product and quantity

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I need help for implementing HTML Form that user can select certain product from input element(e.g drop down) and then for each product add quantity.
the form should have capability for order multiple product.

products are in DB and my repository has method that return `IEnumerable<dynamic>` which I wanna use for iterate the products.

How should I design a html form?

On the server side form will be processing with handler class that inherit `IHttpHandler` within the `ProcessRequest` method.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "how"? You have all the steps except writing the HTML already down. Just do it?

Comment: I don't want to mess my form with unlimited number of drop down and text input, how I write a form that adding more drop down and qty input after user fill the first one? and how I retrieve that form with "POST" ?

Comment: You can dynamically add objects to the DOM-Tree with Javascript, number them and iterate over them later in your RequestHandler, for example

Comment: thanks, can you give me a real code example? mostly for js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hardly do vanilla js, so the following is [from a jQuery-blog](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery).

The Javascript-code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

var x = 1; //initial text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
}) 
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

You would have to make some minimal changes: Remove the limiter, properly set the id/name you want, name the classes according to your CSS.